# Pandas datatype inference

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having troubles with datatype inference and therefore I decided to map datatype manually, however I have discovered I can't recognize Pandas datatype as expected.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

pd_to_pa_dtypes = {"object": pa.string(), "string": pa.string(), "double": pa.float64(),
                       pd.Int32Dtype(): pa.int32(), "int64": pa.int64(),
                       pd.Int64Dtype(): pa.int64(), "datetime64[ns]": pa.timestamp("ns", tz="UTC"),
                       pd.StringDtype(): pa.string(), '<M8[ns]': pa.timestamp("ns", tz="UTC")}

date = pd.to_datetime(["30/04/2021", "28/04/2021"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df = pd.DataFrame(date)

print(df[0].dtype)  # which print datetime64[ns]

pd_to_pa_dtypes[df[0].dtype]  # KeyError: dtype('<M8[ns]')

# However I inserted in my dictionary both "datetime64[ns]" and "<M8[ns]", also if i check datatypes

df[0].dtype == "datetime64[ns]"  # True
df[0].dtype == "<M8[ns]"  # True
```

This happens also for some other datatypes, for example I had problems with int64, while some are mapped as expected.

Comment: try  `pd_to_pa_dtypes[df[0].dtype.str]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
type(df[0].dtype) # is numpy.dtype and not str
```

therefore when you try to access the value in `pd_to_pa_dtypes` dictionary you get an error as `df[0].dtype` it is not the same as the key `str` you have in `pd_to_pa_dtypes`.

Now to your next potential question, you get true when your run the followings due to the implementation of `__eq__` of `dtype` class.

```
df[0].dtype == "datetime64[ns]"  # True
df[0].dtype == "<M8[ns]" # True
```

So to conclude with, use the str representation of your `dtype` object as follows:

```
pd_to_pa_dtypes[df[0].dtype.str]
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try convert_dtypes() in Pandas to Convert columns to best possible dtypes using dtype. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(date, dtype="datetime64[ns]")
pd_to_pa_dtypes[df[0].dtype]`

Still gives me error, i'm not mapping correctly datatypes into my dictionary